# Which is correct? This connective tissue is "fascia" or "a fascia"?

Tags: word-usage, uncountable-nouns

Developers are constantly stealing words from other disciplines. One we've recently acquired is *fascia,* which [Michael Feathers explains in a blog post](https://michaelfeathers.silvrback.com/orange-code):

> Each section [of an orange] is covered with white fiber called fascia. This fiber is very different from the pulp inside of it — the part that makes the orange orange.
>
> Not surprisingly, nature uses the same playbook for other structures. Muscles have fascia too. It’s the surface layer around muscle. Fascia is like skin or the membrane of a cell. It’s all the same pattern.

I saw someone call a bit of code "[a fascia](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/440778/can-you-have-too-much-unit-test-coverage/440779?noredirect=1#comment967951_440779)"

> The boundary between the controller and the mediator's handler is kinda arbitrarily-imposed, thus it's a fascia.

I thought, that's not right. Fascia is a mass noun (or is that uncountable?). No need for an "a".

I can't find a definition that makes this clear, that would show I'm right. Now I'm not sure if I am. Am I barking up the right tree with "mass nouns"? If we're going to steal this word can you help us use it correctly?

Comment: If they are going to steal the word, why can't they decide their own usage? But OTOH does the commenter say "a code" and "informations" and "softwares"? The language has been wrecked anyway.

Comment: @WeatherVane The first link outlines our usage but I'll make an attempt. It's structural code. Code that doesn't make decisions. Just connects other bits of code together. Contrasts with behavioral code. The "commenter" appears to be a [native English speaker](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/440778/131624) wrestling with a new word. That's what I am myself so I thought I'd gather some proof before nit picking.

Comment: You are probably right, and OutstandingBill should have written "thus it's fascia code."

Comment: @WeatherVane ok, how can I show that?

Comment: ...but then again, in the building trade, a fascia is not a mass noun. It is a particular object.

Comment: @WeatherVane maybe I'm thinking of this wrong. I can describe code as being good or bad. But it would sound weird to describe some code as "a good"

Comment: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fascia#examples) has lots of meanings that sound like they should be countable; it quotes a car magazine "The Outback Wilderness does not get an upgraded fascia." Google Books also has several examples of "a fascia", both in physiology and car design. You are supposed to do basic research before asking questions here.

Comment: @candied_orange There's absolutely nothing wrong with "a good", and the term has at least three meanings I can think of.